Ubuntu 22.04 corrupt screen font
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 with gnome 42.09 on 2 different systems and they both have the same problem. From time to time I will notice that the words across the top where the clock and calendar are supposed to be are missing several letters. If I try to go to system properties the menu is missing most of its letters.
Here is a screenshot:

I am posting this because it just happened on the 2nd system which is an 8th gen Intel Dell desktop with a fresh install of 22.04.4 and an AMD rx4200 video card. The other system that has this issue is a 7th gen Intel Dell laptop with integrated Intel video.
I don't know where to look for error messages. I don't see anything in dmesg
https://pastebin.com/wyZV3cu9
If I reboot the fonts are fine again.
I googled "troubleshoot fonts in gnome"
I tried fc-cache -s and then alt-f2 and restart, but the message I got was restart is not available on wayland. As I typed restart all the letters were blank.
If I go into display properties and change the scale from %200 to %100 and then revert the fonts are repaired. Now I can do alt-f2 and type a command with visible letters.
I don't know how to reproduce it.
I suspect it is a bug. If I can get some guidance I will provide all the info I can. This only happens maybe once a week.

I still have the same problem except I have a new computer now. Another Dell optiplex with 8th gen intel i5. I am using the same video card. This is a new installation and this is ubuntu 24.04 (fresh installation. not upgrade.) I am having the same issue now. I have seen this issue for years and I have always used the latest ubuntu lts.  I know I saw it in 20.04.   I had to reboot to clear the issue. output of 'uptime  13:39:31 up 30 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.43, 0.49, 0.50'

Here is output of 'sudo journalctl --since=2024-05-15 --no-pager >> journalctl.txt' .  pastebin.se Screen capture link
